# How to get jobParameters in spring batch 3.0 version

Tags: spring, batch-file, parameters, jobs

I am getting the job parameters value as below using Spring batch version 2.1.8

```
List<JobInstance> jobInstance = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(job.getName(), 0, 1);
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();    

if (!jobInstance.isEmpty()) {
    jobParameters = jobInstance.get(0).getJobParameters();
}
```

It's working as expected.

I am trying to get the same job parameters as below code using Spring batch version 3.0.0 and I knew job `getJobParameters()` was moved to `JobExecution` class from `JobInstance`

```
List<JobInstance> jobInstance = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(job.getName(), 0, 1);
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters();

if (!jobInstance.isEmpty()) {
    JobInstance lastInstance = jobInstance.get(0);
    List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.get(lastInstance);
    jobParameters = jobExecutions.get(0).getJobParameters();
}
```

It's always empty. Could you please let me know how to get the job parameters using spring batch version 3?

Comment: This code was works perfectly.